# Backlight on Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 10.1 is not working after dropping it

Tags: screen, backlight

My Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 10.1 tablet was dropped. It comes on and the screen is fine, however, the screen is black. I can see the screen with a flashlight, though. Can this be fixed, and if so, how?

Comment: The hard thing to say about this issue is what else may have been damaged in the fall? Obviously the screen, but what other hardware/ribbons/connectors etc? It is hard to depend on a visual inspection because there are many times where chipsets look fine but aren't running properly. Replacing screen alone is tricky. I suggest you instead go to service center or some repair shop. In my guess its the digitizer that might be damaged but I am no pro in field of hardware repairing.